# What does it mean for the momentum operator P to satisfy P|n>=hn|n>?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Using periodic boundary conditions to analyze momentum eigenstates on the circle $S^1$, we have the momentum operator $P=-i\hbar\frac{d}{d\phi}$ which satisfies $P|n>=\hbar n|n>$ (for clarity, |n> is meant to represent ket(n)).

I don't understand what the second half of that statement means. The |n> on either side of the equation makes this seem like a Schrödinger equation to me, but I'm not sure where the $\hbar n$ comes into play—perhaps as an eigenvalue?

I also don't understand the significance of this condition being satisfied once we have shown that $P=-i\hbar\frac{d}{d\phi}$ is the momentum operator on $S^1$.

If anyone is able to clarify this, I would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you read this ? Even the most basic introductions to QM that I know of contain the following:  $P=-i\hbar\frac{d}{d\phi}$ is the *definition* of the momentum operator $P$. When $|n\rangle$ is an *eigenstate* of $P$ this eigenstate satisfies $P|n\rangle=\hbar n|n\rangle$ where $\hbar n$ is an *eigenvalue*. I admit that the notation $n$ as part of the eigenvalue and $|n\rangle$ as the eigenstate (function) can be a bit confusing for the beginner.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you! This makes sense to me, I understand now. This is from Woit's textbook.

Comment: Kets are standardly written $|\psi\rangle$, where $\psi$ is a function. For this operator there is an $\mathbb N$-indexed set of eigenfunctions, but to save chalk, instead of picking a Greek letter, say $\phi$, and writing   $|\phi_n\rangle$, physicists decided to just write  $|n\rangle$.